# numpy: summing every element of numpy array with every element of another

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm coming to python from Matlab. In Matlab, given two vectors that are not necessarily the same length, they can be added if one is a row vector and one is a column vector.

```
v1 = [1 3 5 7]

v2 = [2 4 6]'

v1 + v2

ans =

 3     5     7     9
 5     7     9    11
 7     9    11    13
```

I am trying to produce the same behavior in python given two numpy arrays. Looping first came to mind:

```
import numpy as np
v1 = np.array([1,3,5,7])
v2 = np.array([2,4,6])
v3 = np.empty((3,4,))
v3[:] = np.nan

for i in range(0,3):
    v3[i,:] = v1 + v2[i]
```

Is there a more concise and efficient way?

Comment: In your MATLAB `size(v1)` is (1,4), `size(v2)` is (3,1).  Just make the `numpy` arrays the same shape.  (though the `numpy` `v1` is ok with (4,) shape).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

v1 = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])
v2 = np.array([2, 4, 6])

v1 + v2[:, None]
```

You can read more about [numpy's broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
for i in v2:
  z = []
  for j in v1:
    z.append(i+j)
  
  print(z)
```

Comment: You typically don't want to use `for` loops with numpy arrays. Vectorized approaches are often faster and cleaner.