# How to turn a numpy vector into a matrix, where each column in the matrix contains a range around the respective element in the initial vector?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Say I have a numpy vector array:

`array([1, 2, 3])`

and I want to convert this vector into a matrix where each column takes a range of +/- 2 around the respective element in the initial vector, such that my output matrix is:

```
array([[-1,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  5]])
```

what is the best (preferably vectorized) way to do this?

Comment: Another recent question answers this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63286737/numpy-summing-every-element-of-numpy-array-with-every-element-of-another

Comment: thanks, so it seems like I'd still have to iterate over (or at least have one operation for) each element in the initial vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the following one-liner:

```
result = a + np.array([-1, 0, 1])[:, np.newaxis]
```

(I think, a more elegant solution).

The result is:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

## Edit

If the range depends on some parameter, say *rng*, you can do it as:

```
rng = 2   # From x-2 to x+2
result = a + np.arange(-rng, rng + 1)[:, np.newaxis]
```

getting:

```
array([[-1,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  5]])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've realized I want to solve a more general problem now (I've edited the question to account for this): basically, the output matrix should grow dynamically as a function of the range around the initial vector

Comment: awesome, thanks! I guess in the future too when I edit a question I should leave the original as is and tack the edit to the bottom 